# How to display image on axis using pushbutton in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I am using GNU Octave 4.2.1. on Linux Debian. I am trying to make a button (in Octave called `pushbutton`) to open images like jpeg files and display to axis. So far my code is shown below:

```
%image preview
cmdOpenImage = uicontrol(
  mainForm = "style", "pushbutton", "string", "OPEN THE IMAGE",
  "position", [100,630, 100, 30]
)
```

Still working for the button, the progress is shown below:

```
%image preview
cmdOpenImage = uicontrol(
  mainFrm =  "style", "pushbutton", 
              "string", "OPEN THE IMAGE",
              "position", [100,630, 100, 30],
              "ButtonDownFcn", {@previewImage, "1"}
)

function previewImage(h, e, a1)
  i = imread('donuts.jpg');
imshow(i);  
endfunction
```

My prev application on image processing in MATLAB is shown below:

```
function cmdOpenImage_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[a, b] = uigetfile();
i = imread([a, b]);
guidata(hobject, handles);
axes(handles.PreviewImage);
imshow(i);
```

Image of prev app on image processing in MATLAB:

[image: pushbutton displayed image on axes in matlab when clicked]

Pushbutton displayed image on axes when clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got syntax errors in your code, and the logic is a bit muddled, but it's enough to get an idea what you're trying to do. Here's a working version:

```matlab
%% In file 'imageViewer.m'
function imageViewer ()
  MainFrm = figure ( ...
    'position', [100, 100, 250, 350]); 

  TitleFrm = axes ( ... 
    'position', [0, 0.8, 1, 0.2], ... 
    'color',    [0.9, 0.95, 1], ...
    'xtick',    [], ... 
    'ytick',    [], ...  
    'xlim',     [0, 1], ... 
    'ylim',     [0, 1] );

  Title = text (0.05, 0.5, 'Preview Image', 'fontsize', 30);

  ImgFrm = axes ( ...
    'position', [0, 0.2, 1, 0.6], ... 
    'xtick',    [], ... 
    'ytick',    [], ...
    'xlim',     [0, 1], ... 
    'ylim',     [0, 1]);

  ButtonFrm = uicontrol (MainFrm, ...
    'style',    'pushbutton', ... 
    'string',   'OPEN THE IMAGE', ...
    'units',    'normalized', ...
    'position', [0, 0, 1, 0.2], ...
    'callback', { @previewImage, ImgFrm });
end

%% callback subfunction (in same file)
function previewImage (hObject, eventdata, ImageFrame)
  [fname, fpath] = uigetfile();
  Img = imread (fullfile(fpath, fname));
  axes(ImageFrame);
  imshow(Img, []);
  axis image off
end
```

Then run `imageViewer()` from your terminal.

[image] ----------->
[image]

Comment: +  for the donuts (code). Btw if you add some extra toppings on these donuts (i.e. use ellipsis), MATLAB users will be able to enjoy (execute) these donuts (code) as well. 

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I think we should add such examples to the GNU Octave wiki. Do I have permission to use it there?

Comment: @Andy sorry, no idea why I didn't spot / reply to this! (obviously the answer is yes)